# Changing table hline options in R with gt

Tags: r, gt

I am using the gt package to create tables. According the the documentation ([see here](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/tab_options.html#ref-examples)) there are table options to adjust hline details (e.g., table_body.hlines.style, table_body.hlines.width, etc.). The problem is that there are no value options provided. What are the potential style types to which table_body.hlines.style can be set? I have searched both the gt documentation (which is vast) and on forums but can find no answers.

Edit: I am outputting the table to a .tex file via gtsave, if that matters.

Comment: Have you tried with base R line styles: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-line-types-how-to-change-line-types-of-a-graph-in-r-software#:~:text=The%20different%20line%20types%20available,for%20%E2%80%9Cdashed%E2%80%9D%2C%20%E2%80%A6.

Comment: It appears not. If I use “dashed” as the style, I still get the default hlines in the resulting table. R doesn’t complain about that selection, it just doesn’t change the table. But then, R doesn’t complain if I use “foo” as the line type either. Also, I should have mentioned (and I will edit the original question to reflect) that I am attempting to output the table as a .tex LaTex file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `gt()`, the line style the options are `"solid"` (the default), `"dashed"`, or `"dotted"`.

`Weight` is given in pixels. The default is 1 pixel.

The `color` can be defined with a color name or with a hexadecimal color code. The default is `"#000000"` (black).

Comment: This is helpful, except that these options seem to do nothing for tables saved in .tex format. They work for .html output just fine. Really what I am looking to do is to remove the \toprule and \bottomrule that is output with latex tables made by gt().

Comment: What you could do then, I suppose, is retain the `.tex` file that `knit` produces and process out those two rules some other way.

Comment: Yes, this is what I have ended up doing, @rdelrossi. It feels like a "hacky" solution, but it does work. As you did answer the question regrading line option choices, I am upvoting and accepting your answer. I also noted that "none" works as a line option if the output is HTML (none of the choices seem to do anything if the output is LaTex). If possible, would you post a source for where those options are available (either in the gt documentation or elsewhere)? Thanks!

Comment: Appreciate the upvote, @hallque. My experiments found, as you did, that nothing seemed to translate to the tex output, though since the output was pretty nicely formatted it should be a simple matter to filter it out. Presume that you know about `keep_tex` under `pdf_document` in the YAML. The argument options themselves are documented in comments in the `gt` source on Github, I believe in `helpers.R`.